# Button have different URL based on condition

Tags: javascript, html

I'm beginner in Code. I want to create button that have different url based on condition that user choose.

So for example the button called "Book Now"
I have to package using span: Standard and Premium

My plan is, if user choose "standard" the button will be have "html://blablabla.com/standard
and if user choose "premium" the url will be "html://blablabla.com/premium

I was wondering how it can be possible in html and javascript?

Comment: can you please post some code and show what you have working so far?

Comment: So it's not really a button, it's a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)?

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal the code is just have <span> to define standard package and premium package, also button with a href

Comment: @ray nah it's still button

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do that with HTML and JS. Here is a quick example.

```js
// Get the elements
const input = document.querySelector('select');
const link = document.querySelector('a');

// Add an event listner on the input
input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  // set the URL (Note: you could add a switch statement to assign the correct URL for each value)
  link.setAttribute('href', `http://${e.target.value}.com`);
  link.innerHTML = e.target.value
})
```

```html
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

Go to website of <a>...</a>
```

Comment: how if we implement span and section not option like that?

Comment: Why would you want to use `span` and `section`?

Answer (score 0):

I did something like that a while ago. This might answer your question. I changed the values in the code based on your question.

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="stand-prem" class="choice" value="standard" checked> Standard
  <input type="radio" name="stand-prem" class="choice" value="premium"> Premium
  <button class="redirect">Book Now</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
// get the redirect (book now) button in the program
        const redirect_btn = document.querySelector('.redirect');
       
        // bind the event and call a function
        redirect_btn.onclick = function(){
       
              // get the value of the checked radio button
              const radio_choice = document.querySelector('input[name="stand-prem"]:checked').value;
       
              // redirect based on the choice
              if(radio_choice === 'standard'){
                    window.location.href = `html://blablabla.com/${radio_choice}`;
              }else if(radio_choice === 'premium'){
                    window.location.href = `html://blablabla.com/${radio_choice}`;
            }
        }
```